# auto generating a new <div> on video upload

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, automation

I display videos on my website from my youtube channel (embedded). Is there a way of automatically showing a new video, in a new html container when i upload a new video to youtube? effectivly the html container will not exist until the video has been uploaded to youtube and once it has, the new container is created on my site and the new video is displayed?

Comment: use web services... try to implement thin concept in your website...

Comment: Thank you for your reply @vino20 , i'll have a look and see if i can figure it out.